# Maple to solve differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

Suppose that a hole is now drilled directly from the surface of the Earth at the
North Pole, all the way through the centre to the surface at the South Pole.
A particle of mass m is dropped into this hole from a resting position at the
North Pole at time $t = 0$
Suppose that the particle is subjected to a viscous resistive drag force
proportional to the mass of the particle and its velocity:

:$ F_D$ = β[$\frac{
d r(t)}{dt}]^2$
sgn$\frac{dr(t)}{dt}$, where sgn(x) = $\frac{x}{
|x|}$
is the sign of variable x.
,$ k^2 = GM/R^3 = g/R$
and the equation becomes $\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}$=-β[$\frac{
d r(t)}{dt}]^2$
sgn$\frac{dr(t)}{dt}$-$k^2$r(t)

a)In this case, the equation of motion cannot be solved analytically using the
methods that we have developed in class. Using the Maple procedure
RungeKuttaIVP 2D, find the numerical solution to equation (3) for $\beta = 10−7$
and (ii) $\beta = 10−2$
and, by plotting solutions on a single graph over the same
timespan as in Q2(b), show that the motion exhibits damped oscillations in
one of these cases but not the other.

Ok, so from this question I have set the initial conditions using the above information, $ICS = r(0)=R$, $(D(r))(0)=0$;

and I tried solving it with maple

[image]

really stuck from there any help will be appreciated.

Comment: also tried to solve with dsolve command and then use runge kutta but dsolve command dosent seem to work

Comment: Create the list of lists made via `[seq([tval[i],Y1val[i]],i=0..nmax)]` and check that it truly is a list of lists of pairs of numeric values. We do not have access to your 3rd party `RungeKuttaIVP_2D` command. But how does it assign values into `tval` and `Y1val`? Are you saying that your command assigns to those global names as merely a side-effect?? Note that the error message you obtained will occur if `tval` and `Y1val` are still unassigned! Perhaps you are supposed to assign the results from `RungeKuttaIVP_2D` to those names?